# Dataframe Nested Dict inside List - retrieve 'id' value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

```
['{"data":{"attributes":{"title":"Contract 1","AnnualValue":0},"id":1,"type":"contract"}}',
 '{"data":{"attributes":{"title":"Contract 2","AnnualValue":0},"id":2,"type":"contract"}}',
 '{"data":{"attributes":{"title":"Contract 3","AnnualValue":0},"id":3,"type":"contract"}}']
```

I have the above data frame and need to 'pull' the 'id' value. tried converting to json etc but struggling to get the value. Is anyone able to point me in the right direction - 5 hours of googling has just led me up the garden path!!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can display that data in a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

data_list = ['{"data":{"attributes":{"title":"Contract 1","AnnualValue":0},"id":1,"type":"contract"}}',
 '{"data":{"attributes":{"title":"Contract 2","AnnualValue":0},"id":2,"type":"contract"}}',
 '{"data":{"attributes":{"title":"Contract 3","AnnualValue":0},"id":3,"type":"contract"}}']

new_data_list = []
for x in data_list:
    new_data_list.append((json.loads(x)['data']['id'], json.loads(x)['data']['type'], json.loads(x)['data']['attributes']['title'], json.loads(x)['data']['attributes']['AnnualValue']))
df = pd.DataFrame(new_data_list, columns = ['Id', 'Type', 'Title', 'Annual Value'])
print(df)
```

Which returns:

|  | Id | Type | Title | Annual Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | contract | Contract 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 2 | contract | Contract 2 | 0 |
| 2 | 3 | contract | Contract 3 | 0 |

Answer (score 1):

```py
import json

json_list = [
    '{"data":{"attributes":{"title":"Contract 1","AnnualValue":0},"id":1,"type":"contract"}}',
    '{"data":{"attributes":{"title":"Contract 2","AnnualValue":0},"id":2,"type":"contract"}}',
    '{"data":{"attributes":{"title":"Contract 3","AnnualValue":0},"id":3,"type":"contract"}}'
]

ids = [
    json.loads(json_body)["data"]["id"]
    for json_body in json_list
]
```

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer - I will upvote as I may not have been totally clear!
It is currently a nested dict inside a list and I need to evaluate each row in turn rather than just returning the full ids inside - however you have given me food for thought so thankyou